# How to move address search box in qgis2web plugin?

Tags: qgis, javascript, qgis2web

I am using 2.22.0 version of qgis2web plugin and when the plugin provide the address search box that is placed on the right side of the screen. I am using Leaflet map. Now I want to edit the script and move my searchbox to the left side of screen. My question is which script and which part of code I need to change in order to solve my problem? I searched for it in js folder but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `index.html` in a text editor, and search for `L.Control.OSMGeocoder()`. Add options inside the parentheses: `L.Control.OSMGeocoder({position: 'topright'})`. The position values you can use are listed at http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#control.

Comment: I have just changed it to ({position: 'topleft'})